# Bind paramerts in Object if those present there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am receiving an API call at my server with parameters

```
first_name , :last_name , :age
```

etc

I want to bind those params to my object against which user is having attribute with same name , like i want to have these in `user[first_name] , user[:last_name]`

so that I can just put the complete user object into database in following way ,

`User.new(params[:user])` or `User.new(some_hash)`

I dont want to use the following ,

```
User.new(:first_name=>params[:first_name],:last_name=>params[:last_name])
```

thanks in advance for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
user = User.new
params.each do |key,value|
  user[key] = value if user.attribute_names.include?(key.to_s)
end
```

Note, however, that you should protect sensitive attributes of your `User` model with `attr_protected` or `attr_accessible` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Writing that functionality into `User.initialize` can take care of this:

```
def initialize(args={})
  args.each_with_key do |key,val|
    instance_variable_set("@#{key}", val)
  end
end
```

This of course has no validation and does not protect your object from bad data. For example, if you want to make sure only valid accessible attributes are being set, add `if respond_to? key` to end end of line 3.